# Cannot convert source type 'System Linq IQueryable<decimal>' to target type decimal

Tags: c#, linq, decimal

My linq code is;

```
decimal A = (from _a in parameterEntities.BlockOfBuildingsAndParcels
                    where _a.status == 1 && _a.isActive == "1"
                    select _a.areaOfDecar)
```

`_a.areaOfDecar` type is `decimal` but it is still doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign an `IQueryable<decimal>` to a `decimal` as you need to select only `one` value you need to use `FirstOrDefault` to select only one record:

```
decimal A = (from _a in parameterEntities.BlockOfBuildingsAndParcels
             where _a.status == 1 && _a.isActive == "1"
             select _a.areaOfDecar).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thank u it is working but if find another way
i prefer use Single() that is also workin

Comment: @berry yeah you can use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`